# C++ input global variables accessible across several classes

Tags: c++, global-variables, global

I'm developing a project that takes several command-line arguments, and uses these as parameters for subsequent simulations.  (I want to run a large number of experiments in a batch).

What's the best way to set global variables at runtime?   Global in terms of:  the variables may change in the duration of a run, but should be accessible across a large number of classes.

Currently I read them into a Config object which I include in other classes.  If anyone has better ideas (xml?) I'm all ears.

Thanks!

Comment: is your program multithreaded?

Comment: if your hardware is multicore, passing these variables as parameters would generally be the better approach (shorter time to process all inputs) when you want to take advantage of concurrent batch execution…

Comment: No it's not multithreaded, but it may well be in the future.  Thanks for the suggestion of passing as parameters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bring all the related **variables under one roof** for ease of access. 2 approaches are possible:

### (1) Namespace globals

```
namespace Configuration {
  extern int i;
  extern bool b;
  extern std::string s;
}
```

### (2) Class static members

```
class Configuration {  // provide proper access specifier
  static int i;
  static bool b;
  static std::string s;
}
```

To track them nicely, use getter()-setter() methods as wrapper inside namespace/class.
With getters-setters you can handle them in a thread-safe way, if the program demands.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I really appreciate it.  I'll go with class static members and getter/setter methods.